# Resource compilation failed

Tags: android-studio

I work with Android Studio 3.2 and I've done a firebase connection to get connected to the part of the register with the app I'm building.

Here's screenshots of where I'm seeing the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iuJp.jpg & https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cy29B.jpg

```
Android resource compilation failed
Output:  C:\Users\ERIK\AndroidStudioProjects\FirebaseAuthDemo\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher.xml:12: error: not well-formed (invalid token).

Command: C:\Users\ERIK\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\92d92d266c9089a895db65475d7e7f04\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        C:\Users\ERIK\AndroidStudioProjects\FirebaseAuthDemo\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        C:\Users\ERIK\AndroidStudioProjects\FirebaseAuthDemo\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\ic_launcher.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26/ic_launcher.xml` file is incorrect, on line 12. This is often caused by an incorrect character being there, e.g. a semicolon or full stop.

You can delete this file if you want a quick fix, otherwise open up the file see what the compiler has highlighted as the issue on line 12. If you can't work out what's wrong, edit your question with the file's contents and any additional errors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i see the correct your answer but i send your code here for see you who is problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
    <component name="AndroidLayouts">
        <shared>
            <config />
        </shared>
    </component>
    <component name="CMakeSettings">
        <configurations>
            <configuration
                CONFIG_NAME="Deb
                PROFILE_NAME="Debug
```

@JakeSteam